# Why is my Laravel upload generating a HTTP error 504

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk. The app has a form which uploads an excel file and saves each row to a database record. If the Excel file has less than five rows, I am redirected back to my success page. The rows are saved to each database record as expected.

If the Excel file has more than six records, I get a page took too long to respond HTTP 504 error. I have inserted the code below on the Controller which handles the upload:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '3000');
```

On the Elastic Beanstalk PHP configuration, I have also set the max execution time to 3000. But I am still getting the HTTP 504 error. However, I notice that all rows are saved to the database. This should mean that the Controller code continues to process even when I get the error? How do I resolve?

Thank you

Here's the sample code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;
use Excel;
use File;
use DB;
use Validator,
    Carbon\Carbon,
    Auth,
    App\User,
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class ExcelUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
       #code goes here
    }

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        #this method uploads the excel file
        if($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
           ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');#set to 5 mins
           $path = $request->file->getRealPath();
           $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
           if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
           {
             foreach ($data as $rows) {
               foreach ($rows as $row) {
                   $name = $row->name;#first column
                   $address = $row->address;
                   #code to save to database
               }
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be several reasons for a gateway timeout error, without your code sample, we won't be able to guide you.

Comment: Did you checked `/storage/logs/laravel.log/`? Did it contains a stack trace relative to your issue?

Comment: I've added the code. I'll check out the log file. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

No matter how much max_execution time I set, I always get a timeout.

The workaround I did was to handle the upload via AJAX. I used JavaScript to read each row of the Excel file. Each row is submitted via AJAX POST to a method defined in the Route. The method is parallel to the sample in the question.

I am also looking at Laravel Queue to handle the request.